# Test Impact View does not record data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

So i'm getting started a bit with unit testing in C# (using the built in testing tools). The tutorial i was following mentioned the Test Impact View. Told me to just open the window and click the link to enable the feature.

The window says there is no test impact data available and need to run the tests (which i do). But nothing happens then. It keeps giving me that message. I have checked the options to see if the link was just bugging out or so and didn't enable the feature.

So, does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have VS2010 Premium or Ultimate, otherwise VS2010 professional only have Unit Testing take a look http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: Hmm, strange, i do have that. The tab shows up. But it never records the test data